# Is is possible to use for-each with provider alias

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider

I have multiple configurations for a provider, so I defined different provider aliases.
I then have another resource that I need to create for each provider. So instead of defining each resource individually, I tried to use for-each.

However, when it comes to set the "provider" property of the resource, I can't get Terraform to recognize variables, or functions, or for-each.
Example:

Suppose I have these provider aliases: "vendor.alias1", "vendor.alias2"

I am trying to define something like this:

```
resource vendor_resource_type "my_resource_list" {
    for-each = toset(["alias1","alias2"])
    ...
    provider = vendor."${each.key}"
}
```

I also tried to use lookup function (e.g provider = lookup(a map of provider aliases)) to no avail.

Is this even possible with Terraform?

Comment: Sadly its not possible.

Comment: Additionally I believe this feature has been under consideration for some time now, so it may be implemented, but also it has been a long time.